# Do we really need to perform MS SQL database integrity check regularly?

Tags: database, sql, integrity

What's the benefit of performing regular database integrity checks? 
Can't we just perform it when there's a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responding to the title:

Only if you like your data to not be corrupted, or at least if you want to know as soon as possible so you can restore from backup / minimize data loss...

From [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139858.aspx):

> The Check Database Integrity task checks the allocation and structural
>   integrity of all the objects in the specified database.

You could check the database for consistency after you know that there's a problem, but that's rather like washing and waxing your car after it has set on fire.  The Integrity check is an early-warning and preventative maintenance step.

Make a scheduled task and move on with life.